# Linq: Select KeyValuePair from dictionary where value is a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a field that looks like:

```
public Dictionary<ClassA, List<ClassB>> MyDict;
```

Assume that:

```
public class ClassA 
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
 }

public class ClassB 
{
    public string Tag;
    public string Text;
 }
```

I'm trying to define a query that is of `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ClassA,IEnumerable<ClassB>>` type where I define a condition on the value of `ClassB.Tag`. I tried things like:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ClassA,IEnumerable<ClassB>> q =
    MyDict.Where(pair => pair.Value.Any(b => b.Tag == "a tag"));
```

But obviously the above is not what I need because it returns the whole `List<ClassB>` if *any* item matches that condition, while what I want is to return an `IEnumrable` or a `List` of items that match the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dotNetFiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WiJl1U)

You need to construct the IEnumerable from a call to ToDictionary, where you use a projection to only take the matching BClass from the list and only take the result from that set where values in the BClass list were actually matched.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ClassA,List<ClassB>>> q = MyDict.ToDictionary(
    k => k.Key, 
    k => k.Value.Where(b => b.Tag == "10").ToList()
).Where(kv => kv.Value.Any());
```

Comment: is it the case that `ToDictionary()` is going to enumerate the query? I may have some performance concerns in my actual implementation. I may have nested calls to functions that return `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ClassA,List<ClassB>>>`.

Comment: It appears that yes, ToDictionary will enumerate the query. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,a6091311eadfdd8a,references

Comment: Seeing as how `MyDict` was `Dictionary<ClassA, List<ClassB>>`, which was already concrete, it didn't seem like that would be an issue though.

Comment: Ok, but if I have some code statment that would look like: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ClassA,List<ClassB>>> q = X.GetPairsQueryByTag(tag, X.GetPairsQueryByText(Text, X.MyDict);` where `X` is an object that has `MyDict` field, and `GetPairsQueryByTag()` and `GetPairsQueryByText()` filter on `ClassB.Tag` and `ClassB.Text` fields respectivly. Would I be enumerating the dictionary multiple times?

Comment: It is a little hard to discern what you are describing exactly, as the nuance between different versions would lead to different answers, and also as your original statement is a little hard to parse (there is a lacking `)` which is kind of confusing). If you are needing to combine the search between text *and* tag, and you use two calls, you may iterate the dictionary twice. If you nest the calls, same thing. You should probably just write one statement that does both. That said, enumerating twice shouldn't be a problem unless there are more than like 100k items, or if it' not in memory.